# How to see code coverage of Spock tests in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, unit-testing, code-coverage, spock

I am working on a Java project in Eclipse. I use Spock to test my code.

My project contains two directories:

- a src directory containing all my Java files
- a test directory containing all my Spock tests

I don't use any automation build system.

How can I see the code coverage of my Spock tests?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Spock runner is based on the JUnit runner.

So you do exactly the same as you do with JUnit

1. Go to Menu Help -> Eclipse Marketplace
2. Search for Eclemma Install it and restart Eclipse (after accepting
   licence)
3. Right click on any Spock test (or directly)
4. Select from the menu Coverage as..-> JUnit test

Wait a while and a Coverage window will appear. Enjoy!\

More details are in the official site http://www.eclemma.org/installation.html